# Image rollovers with anchors targeting iframes

Tags: html, css, iframe, anchor, rollover

I have some issues with the website I'm making that I need help resolving. Here's a link to the live example:

http://scissormanmusic.com/index_new4.html

The news, beats, and music rollovers and anchors work fine for me on Firefox 12 and Chrome 16. However, the contact rollover doesn't work and neither does its anchor. The link rollover and anchor work only if you hover on the right 30% of the links.png.

Also, twitter.png doesn't display. I know I uploaded it, and I'm pretty sure I linked to it correctly because it was working fine in Dreamweaver and local tests on browsers.

Comment: 1. Show some debugging effort. 2. Post your code here if you're still having trouble; don't link to the website and make us find what's relevant. 3. Don't put "need basic help please!!" in the title. 4. Ask one question.

Comment: Have you tried Firebug or Chrome Console to debug?

Comment: @minitech, #2 is the most relevant IMO to the question, but I feel you on the other three.

Comment: Also, please use some kind capitalization. (Unless both Shift keys and Caps Lock are broken on your keyboard. In which case, my sincerest condolences.)

Answer (score 1):

Your left menu is overlapping your right menu, as you can see by using Inspect Element:

[image]

Make it smaller, or move the right menu to the front.

```css
#rightMenu {
    z-index: 3; /* Instead of 1 */
}
```

Comment: All that crabbiness... And you still have an answer... Good man.